# ¿ Como agregar atributos HEADER general a los response de mi web service java?

Tags: java-ee, glassfish, jersey

Estoy exponiendo un api rest con Javaee, pero tengo el problema del CORS porque la estoy consumiendo desde una app Angular, se que en cada método del servicio a cada response puedo colocarle un header, pero no quiero agregarle un header a cada response, quiero mas bien algo parecido a un Interceptor que agregue un header a cada Response para así evitar el problema de CORS.

No estoy usando ningún framework, estoy trabajando con netbeans, y mi proyecto tampoco usa un archivo web.xml, ya he buscado soluciones basadas en ese archivo en internet y no me han funcionado. Estoy usando JPA, a partir de las entidades cree el servicio, netbeans permite esa opcion.

Answer (score 0):

Si está utilizando Java EE para exponer una API RESTful, quiere decir que está utilizando JAX-RS -> Jersey, RestEasy o alguna de sus [implementaciones](https://dzone.com/articles/jax-rs-vendor-comparisons-part).

JAX-RS permite crear *generalizaciones* para estos casos. **Eso sí, debe estar utilizando la versión 2.0 como mínimo**

Ese *interceptor* del que habla se llama en este caso `ContainerResponseFilter`. Veamos un ejemplo:

### 1. creamos el filtro [CORS](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)

```
package su.estructura.de.paquetes;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;

public class CORSResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {


        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = responseContext.getHeaders();

        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");        
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");          
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Codingpedia");               

    }
}
```

### 2.

Debemos registrar el nuevo filtro en la app, esto depende de la configuración que tenga.

**A.** Si utiliza JAX-RS junto con javax.ws.rs.core.Application:

Es tan simple como agregar `@Provider` a su filtro, el resto lo hace el framework..

```
@Provider
public class CORSResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {}
```

**B.**Si ha utilizado Jersey como la implementación a JAX-RS **y** ha sobrescrito alguno de los métodos de `ResourceConfig` o `Application` para registrar sus `clases,singletons,etc.` Habrá que registrarlo manualmente:

```
package su.estructura.de.paquetes;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class RESTBootstrap extends ResourceConfig   {

    public RESTBootstrap(){

        register(CORSResponseFilter.class);
        packages("paquetes.que.se", "van.a.escanear");
    }
}
```

Es bastante simple, espero que sea de ayuda.